# accessing filter values with in a "CALCULATED COLUMNS" definition of a Dataset (jinja template)

Tags: apache-superset

With in a "CALCULATED COLUMNS" definition of a Dataset,
is it possible to access the `{{filter_values('some_key')}}` to access the dashboard filter   ?  I can access the values for `{{current_username()}}` and `{{current_user_id()}}` from the column definition just fine. There seems to be nothing returned for filter_values(),
Also what should be passed as the 'some_key' value to the filter_values function for custom filters added to the main dashboard filter?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I guess should work. 'some_key' is the name of the column used in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a filter to the dashboard and 'some_key' is the name of the column of the dataset used by the filter, **not** the filter name.
filter_values('column_filter') returns and object list, so to get the first value use
{{ filter_values('column_filter')|first }}

Don't forget to set the correct scope for the filter!